# Type of 'return this' in a Groovy @Mixin

Tags: groovy, mixins

I have a mixin class that bundles functionality for different types that do not share a common heritage. The mixing is applied using the @Mixin annotation, so it is handled at compile time.

Some of the mixin methods return *this* as the result of a method call. The problem is that the *this* is of the mixing type and not the type of the base class. When I want to work typed in the rest of the application a ClassCastException is thrown saying that the mixing type can not be cast to the base type.

In the example code below `return this` returns an object of type AMixin instead of an Object of type BaseClass.

How can I have `return this` return an object of type BaseClass instead of an object of type AMixin?

```
class AMixin {

  def getWhatIWant(){
    if(isWhatIwant){
      return this
    } else {
      getChildWhatIWant()
    }
  }

  def getChildWhatIWant(){
    for (def child in childred) {
        def whatIWant = child.getWhatIWant()
        if (whatIWant) {
            return whatIWant
        }
    }
    return null
  }
}


@Mixin(AMixin)
class BaseClass {
  boolean isWhatiWant
  List<baseClass> children
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this same situation. I solved it by setting 'this' from the concrete class into a private variable 'me' inside the concrete class and return 'me' in the Mixin classes. For example:

```
class MyMixin {
    def mixinMethod() {
        // do stuff
        return me
    }
}

@Mixin(MyMixin)
class MyConcreteClass {
    private MyConcreteClass me
    MyConcreteClass() {
        me = this
    }
}
```

I feel like it's a bit kludgy, but I think it's a lot simpler than this other solution. I personally need the ability to use the same Mixin in multiple classes, and it sounds like this other proposed solution would not allow for that if you cannot assign multiple Categories to a single Mixin class.

Comment: This solution works, thanks. Since my Mixin had to be initialized, I chose to call this method init(this) with this, so I can pass the "real" this to the Mixin this way - seems a little cleaner to me. However, there is something not right with both workarounds, they shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This approach solved the problem for me, but as Ice09 already says this workaround does not feel right.

Answer (score 2):

I created the class Base added the category to the AMixin Class and the BaseClass extends from Base.....(http://groovy.codehaus.org/Category+and+Mixin+transformations)

Executed this in GroovyConsole I get

BaseClass@39c931fb

```
class Base {
     boolean isWhatIwant
     List<BaseClass> children
}

@Category(Base)
class AMixin {

  def getWhatIWant(){
    if(isWhatIwant){
      return this
    } else {
      getChildWhatIWant()
    }
  }

  def getChildWhatIWant(){
    for (def child in children) {
        def whatIWant = child.getWhatIWant()
        if (whatIWant) {
            return whatIWant
        }
    }
    return null
  }
}


@Mixin(AMixin)
public class BaseClass extends Base {

}

def b = new BaseClass(isWhatIwant:true)
println b.getWhatIWant()
```

EDIT just a DummyClass. I know it's very awkward that It works....I'm sure [Guillaume Laforge](http://glaforge.free.fr/weblog/) could answer how this works...

```
class DummyClass {

}

@Category(DummyClass)
class AMixin {

  def getWhatIWant(){
    if(isWhatIwant){
      return this
    } else {
      getChildWhatIWant()
    }
  }

  def getChildWhatIWant(){
    for (def child in children) {
        def whatIWant = child.getWhatIWant()
        if (whatIWant) {
            return whatIWant
        }
    }
    return null
  }
}


@Mixin(AMixin)
public class BaseClass extends DummyClass {
     boolean isWhatIwant
     List<BaseClass> children
}

def b = new BaseClass(isWhatIwant:true)
println b.getWhatIWant()
```

Comment: What is the effect of the @Category(Base) annotation on the Mixin class? And I assume this is not possible if I have multiple base classes, e.g. BaseA, BaseB & BaseC .

Comment: No, you can not have multiple categories base classes in the Mixin, but you can have multiple mixins with the same category, this helps to have a sort of "multiherarchy". @Category is used in groovy for meta-programming and to extend classes.

Comment: But why would I want to extend the AMixin class with the BaseClass as Category? I only need the AMixin functionality to be available in the BaseClass.

Comment: It's kinda of a redundancy but with the attribute @Category you're telling to the AMixin class that It'll use that object and can only be "mixin / extended" for that kind of object. I'm not a guru of groovy to really know how the meta-programming is working under the hood.....I just tried to answer your question... :) I edit the answer just using that class as a Dummy and leave all in the base class